# write 33 as sum of three cubes to solve 3 as sum of three cubes

Tags: number-theory

I am interested in writing numbers as the sum of three positive or negative cubed integers. This [article](https://www.quantamagazine.org/why-the-sum-of-three-cubes-is-a-hard-math-problem-20191105/) describes how a supercomputer was used to find that

$$33 = 8{,}866{,}128{,}975{,}287{,}528^3 + (−8{,}778{,}405{,}442{,}862{,}239)^3 + (−2{,}736{,}111{,}468{,}807{,}040)^3$$

Apparently they then used that to find a third way of writing 3 as the sum of three cubes - after $1^3+1^3+1^3$ and $4^3+4^3+(-5)^3$:

$$3 = 569{,}936{,}821{,}221{,}962{,}380{,}720^3 + (−569{,}936{,}821{,}113{,}563{,}493{,}509)^3 + (−472{,}715{,}493{,}453{,}327{,}032)^3$$

So our equation $33=x^3+y^3+z^3$ can be rewritten as $33-z^3=x^3+y^3$. Now, $x^3+y^3=(x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2)$. So for each $z$ values, we compute $33-z^3$ and then try to factor it and see if it can be reaarage into the form $(x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2)$. How else can we make improvement to reduce the size of search space to find a way to express 33 as sum of three cubes.  So how does finding 33 as sum of three cubes help find 3 as sum of three cubes?

Comment: ...cubes of what?

Comment: $3 = 1+1+1,\,$ that's it.

Comment: The article didn't say that at all!

Comment: Whole numbers? Negative allowed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The resolution for $33$ didn't help directly for the resolution for $3$. The initial author rather designed an efficient method to tackle the general problem.

In the paper (https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~maarb/papers/cubesv1.pdf), he describes an alternative method based on factorization: if

$$k-z^3=(x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2)$$ then you can try among the $x+y$ that divide $k-z^3$ and solve

$$\begin{cases}x+y=d,\\x^2-xy+y^2=\dfrac{k-z^3}d\end{cases}.$$

The method he used is different.